# maven doesn't download dependencies from local repository whereas url looks good

Tags: eclipse, maven, compilation, dependencies, pom.xml

I am a novice in Maven and my problem is Maven doesn't download dependency whereas the URL is good. Indeed, when I copy-paste the URL on my browser, I can see the pom.

Below is my pom.xml and the result of a `mvn compile` on Eclipse ( Run as -> maven build ... -> compile )

my pom:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>sourCode</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>repo</id>
    <name>repo ref</name>
    <url>https://my.internalrepo/nexus/content/repositories/sdc1-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <name>sourCode</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>  
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.internal.package.package.to.download</groupId>
      <artifactId>sourceCode</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Result of compilation:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< groupId:sourCode >--------------------------
[INFO] Building sourCode 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from : https://my.internalrepo/nexus/content/repositories/sdc1-releases/my/internal/package/package/to/download/sourceCode/3.0.4/sourceCode-3.0.4.pom
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/my/internal/package/package/to/download/sourceCode/3.0.4/sourceCode-3.0.4.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.207 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-28T16:58:22+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sourCode: Could not resolve dependencies for project groupId:sourCode:jar:0.0.1: Failed to collect dependencies at my.internal.package.package.to.download:sourceCode:jar:3.0.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for my.internal.package.package.to.download:sourceCode:jar:3.0.4: Could not transfer artifact my.internal.package.package.to.download:sourceCode:pom:3.0.4 from/to repo (https://my.internalrepo/nexus/content/repositories/sdc1-releases): handshake alert:  unrecognized_name -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

And when I copy paste "https://my.internalrepo/nexus/content/repositories/sdc1-releases/my/internal/package/package/to/download/sourceCode/3.0.4/sourceCode-3.0.4.pom", I can see the pom

I tried to compile with "mvn compile" in terminal, Result:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: my.internalrepo: unknown name or service
```

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

EDIT: There is a difference between when I try to compile when I am connected to the Internet (the URL is not available) and when I am on the local network:

On Internet:

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project [...]: my.internalrepo: Unknown host my.internalrepo -> [Help 1]
```

On local network:

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project [...]: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name -> [Help 1]
```

EDIT2: I tried to download sourceCode-3.0.4.pom via wget, I can if I use "--no-check-certificate"

Comment: "java.net.UnknownHostException: my.internalrepo" is pretty clear. Use an actual, real, reachable, URL.

Comment: I can't write the real URL, the most important is the URL est accessible only in local network and I can access in Browser

Comment: Does changing the internal repo URL from `https://...` to `http://...` fix your issue?

Comment: I tried this but I have the same problem

Comment: Hi all, now it's solved. I did not have certificates to access the repository with maven. Thanks for your help